# Flutter, How to return empty string in DateTime.parse when value is null

Tags: flutter

I passed a json into a class constructor, there is a datetime field but sometimes the return value may be null, I do I display an empty string when the value is null?

```
class dataRecord {
  int id;
  DateTime createdate;
  DateTime? confirmdate;

  dataRecord({
    required this.id,
    required this.createdate,
    this.confirmdate,
  });

  factory dataRecord.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return dataRecord(
      id: json['id'] as int,
      createdate: DateTime.parse(json['createtime']) as DateTime,
      confirmdate: DateTime.parse(json['confirmtime']) as DateTime,
    );
  }
}
```

I tried DateTime.tryParse, but can make it work either.

Comment: confirmdate:json['confirmtime']!=null? DateTime.parse(json['confirmtime']) as DateTime:null;

Comment: You can use confirmdate: json['confirmtime'] != null ? DateTime.parse(json['confirmtime']) as DateTime : ''

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot return an empty string for the field since you already declared the datatype to be `DateTime?` but you can return `null` instead. Replace your class with the one below.

```
class DataRecord {
  int id;
  DateTime createdate;
  DateTime? confirmdate;

  DataRecord({
    required this.id,
    required this.createdate,
    this.confirmdate,
  });

  factory DataRecord.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return DataRecord(
      id: json['id'] as int,
      createdate: DateTime.parse(json['createtime']),
      confirmdate: json['confirmtime'] != null
          ? DateTime.parse(json['confirmtime'])
          : null,
    );
  }
}
```